# How to require a true value in Clarity smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, clarity, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

In my smart contract, I want to check whether a boolean value is true, if not the smart contract should abort or throw an error like

```
(begin
   (require-true value)
   ...continue
)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: For exiting early and returning an error there is `asserts!` (https://docs.blockstack.org/references/language-functions#asserts)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unwrap-panic` in a function, e.g.

```
(define-private (require-true (value bool))
  (unwrap-panic (if value (some true) none))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`asserts!` will return true and continue the execution only if the boolean expression it evaluates is true. If not it will return the thrown-value and exit the current control flow.

Signature is: `(asserts! boolean-expression thrown-value)`

Example that will return `true` and continue execution:

`(asserts! (is-eq 1 1) (err 1))`